# Передача ассоциативного массива с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно передать ассоциативный массив на сервер с помощью jQuery? Имеется следующий массив:

```
arr = [];
arr['param1'] = 'text1';
arr['param2'] = 'text2';
arr['param3'] = 'text3';
```

Обычный способ передачи не работает:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: path,
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'array': arr},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {...}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ассоциативный массив в JS - это объект. Собственно и массив с числовыми ключами - это тоже объект, но инициализация и формирование несколько отличается.

```
var obj = {};
obj.param1 = 'text1';
obj.param2 = 'text2';
obj.param3 = 'text3';

jQuery.ajax({
    url: path,
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'array': obj},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

P.S. Кстати, вот так - `data: obj,` - тоже можно